# Is there any way to select specific case statements based on specific situations?

Tags: delphi, pascal

```
 Direction := TDirection(Random(Succ(Ord(High(TDirection)))));
case Direction of
up:
  begin
    CurrentCell := maze[i, j - 1];
    CurrentCell.Wall := false;
  end;
down:
  begin
    CurrentCell := maze[i, j + 1];
    CurrentCell.Wall := false;
  end;
left:
  begin
    CurrentCell := maze[i - 1, j];
    CurrentCell.Wall := false;
  end;
right:
  begin
    CurrentCell := maze[i + 1, j];
    CurrentCell.Wall := false;
  end;
```

I basically have a 2D array called maze (`[0..19, 0.19]`) in which, from `maze[0,0]` a random direction is picked. If the pointer `CurrentCell` is in any of the cells at the edges of `maze`, being column 0, row 0, row 19 and column 19, there are certain directions that cant be picked. My question is there any way for me to tell the program which directions to randomize from if the `CurrentCell` pointer is in any of the rows and columns listed above?

The directions are created with an enum

```
TDirection = (up, down, left, right);
var
    Direction : TDirection;
```

Comment: You have to deal with it when assigning to "direction", the case is too late. The question is not very clear but if I got it right; no, the compiler cannot read your mind.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I apologise, I wasn't really sure how to phrase it. I've edited it now, so hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Instead of thinking about direction as absolute values (left, right, up, down) think of it as an array of available directions for the position.  So if you can 't move right, then you have an array of 3 directions (left, up, down) and you choose a random index of 0..2.  You could also keep your method and just loop until you pick a valid direction.

Comment: You can check if you can go a specific direction either in the cases or before you enter the case statement. That depends on you. You can have a boolean flag to indicate if the direction was actually taken.

Comment: @Rudy - What if it gets stuck on a non-existing wall till eternity? It's a probability.

Comment: AFAIK, he initializes all elements of the array (a labyrinth) with Wall := True, so that is unlikely. But that is his code. If he can't go anywhere, he creates the exit. <g>

Comment: I was just about to post an answer to your q earlier today about mazes when I found you'd deleted it!

Comment: @MartynA I'm sorry! thanks for taking the time to (try) and answer.

Comment: No worries.  My main point was (going to be) that exactly how you represent the maze makes a *huge* difference to how easy and efficient it is to code it.  The key is to use a matrix where the walls are represents by one int value (e.g. 1)  and the space you can move in is represented by e.g. zeroes.  You can then use a `stack of record` to record the coordinates of the current cell being "explored" and a number which represents which of the N, E, S & W exits from it have already been explored; once you get that bit right, all tthe rest becomes trivial. Anyway ...

Comment: Btw, re. what you ask in this q, it's actually not a good idea to explore routes at random, because that requires you to record more state information on your exploration state than the minimum necessary.  If you always explore exits from the currrent cell in a given order (as in N, E, S, W), if you are currently exploring the S exit (if it exists and isn't blocked by a wall), you don't need to record the fact that you have already looked at possible N and E exits.

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for the tip. Since I asked this question I have started again, as it wasn't really working. Rather than making the cells walls, I'm looking at the walls between cells, and the recursion seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the current coordinate you can determine which directions are available: accumulate available directions and then pick a random one. E.g.:

```
var
  ..
  DirList: TList<TDirection>;
begin
  ..

  DirList := TList<TDirection>.Create;
  try
    if i > 0 then
      DirList.Add(mdUp);
    if i < 19 then
      DirList.Add(mdDown);
    if j > 0 then
      DirList.Add(mdRight);
    if j < 19 then
      DirList.Add(mdLeft);

    case DirList[Random(DirList.Count)] of
      mdUp:    CurrentCell := maze[i, j - 1];
      mdDown:  CurrentCell := maze[i, j + 1];
      mdLeft:  CurrentCell := maze[i - 1, j];
      mdRight: CurrentCell := maze[i + 1, j];
    end;
    CurrentCell.Wall := False;

    ...
```

Without a generic list, this would look like this:

```
var
  ..
  DirList: TList;
begin
  ..

  DirList := TList.Create;
  try
    if i > 0 then
      DirList.Add(Pointer(mdUp));
    if i < 19 then
      DirList.Add(Pointer(mdDown));
    if j < 19 then
      DirList.Add(Pointer(mdLeft));
    if j > 0 then
      DirList.Add(Pointer(mdRight));

    Direction := TDirection(DirList[Random(DirList.Count)]);
    ...
```

I'd really like to do this with a set, which would be a better fit to the context, but it would require helpers to randomize from it.

---

Answering the title question requires having read the original post. The answer is no, after the `case` is compiled to the binary, there's no way to effect existence of individual branches at runtime. You cannot effect branch values either, they must be constants that are resolved at compile time. Fortunately this is not required at all, after all you decide at run time what value the selector will hold and hence which branch will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Add every possible direction into an array of `TDirection` and pick a random element from the array.

Here is a function where the inputs are the maze bounds and the actual position:

```
Type
  TDirection = (up, down, left, right);
  TMazeRect = record lowX,lowY,highX,highY : integer; end;
const
  MyMazeRect : TMazeRect = (lowX:0;lowY:0;highX:19;highY:19);

function RandomRestrictedDirection( const area : TMazeRect; posX,posY : Integer) : TDirection;
var
  dirArray : array[0..3] of TDirection;
  count : Integer;
begin
  count := 0;
  if (posY < area.highY) then begin
    dirArray[count] := up;
    Inc(count);
  end;
  if (posY > area.lowY) then begin
    dirArray[count] := down;
    Inc(count);
  end;
  if (posX > area.lowX) then begin
    dirArray[count] := left;
    Inc(count);
  end;
  if (posX < area.highX) then begin
    dirArray[count] := right;
    Inc(count);
  end;
  Result := dirArray[Random(count)];
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
NewDirection := RandomRestrictedDirection(MyMazeRect,i,j);
```